# Powershell project in visual studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

How do I open a powershell project in visual studio. The project was created in GitLab originally and then put in VSTS, am able to clone it to my local machine but do not see an option to open the project. VS2015 is looking for a soln file or similar files. Am guessing because the project was not initially built in VS2015?

Comment: If there's no *.sln or *.*proj files, then it's not a VS project - are you perhaps talking about a git _repository_?

Comment: My bad, there was a proj file inside...but it is created as a Git repository itself. Am able to open it now.